# Why twitter bootstrap and its main advantage?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Why twitter bootstrap came into existence and what is the main problem it is solving compared to other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why people use css framworks like bootstrap

1. Speeds up your development 
   Reusing a structure is more efficient than re-coding every project from scratch.there is pre made stuffs like forms.. buttons,navigations,dropdowns....etcin bootstrap
2. Enables cross-browser functionality
   eliminate browser-specific bug

3.responsive grid systems